# How concatenation work in MySQL stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, concatenation

Hi this is the sample query i was trying to execute in MySQL. It give out an error when am using the concat function

```
  SELECT @grp :=San_Orange_CS_GRP as santoor_grp ,
  @_11:=power(@grp,0.1)+0.1*@_11 AS concat "@grp" , "_11" ,
  @_12:=power(@grp,0.2)+0.1*@_12 AS concat "@grp" , "_12" 
  FROM DUMMY JOIN (SELECT @_11:=0,@_12:=0) t;
```

When i alter the code and give the column name everytime in the query after AS statement, it works fine. But the problem is i have around 100 columns so i cannot keep on writting the names each and every time i run different market grp

```
   SELECT @grp :=Orange_CS_GRP as Orange_CS_grp ,
   @_11:=power(@grp,0.1)+0.1*@_11 Orange_CS_GRP_11 ,
   @_12:=power(@grp,0.2)+0.1*@_12 AS Orange_CS_GRP_12 
   from DUMMY JOIN (SELECT @_11:=0,@_12:=0) t;
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact query with concat:

SELECT @grp :=San_Orange_CS_GRP as santoor_grp ,
  @_11:=power(@grp,0.1)+0.1*@_11 AS concat(@grp , "_11") ,
  @_12:=power(@grp,0.2)+0.1*@_12 AS concat (@grp , "_12") 
  FROM DUMMY JOIN (SELECT @_11:=0,@_12:=0) t;

use of concat is incorrect in your query..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alias names are identifiers and can't be assigned names from values of a column dynamically.

To do so you can use a stored procedure.

**Example**:

```
drop procedure if exists sp_so_q23692874;

delimiter //

create procedure sp_so_q23692874()
begin
  -- read my comment below this SP.
  SELECT San_Orange_CS_GRP INTO @grp FROM DUMMY LIMIT 1;
  set @grp_name := 'Orange_CS_GRP';

  set @sql := concat( 'SELECT San_Orange_CS_GRP as santoor_grp ' );
  set @sql := concat( @sql, ', @_11 := power( ', @grp, ', 0.1 ) + 0.1 * @_11 ' );
  set @sql := concat( @sql, 'AS `', @grp_name, '_11` ' );
  set @sql := concat( @sql, ', @_12 := power( ', @grp, ', 0.2 ) + 0.1 * @_12 ' );
  set @sql := concat( @sql, 'AS `', @grp_name, '_12` ' ); 
  set @sql := concat( @sql, ' FROM DUMMY JOIN ( SELECT @_11 := 0, @_12 := 0 ) t' );

  prepare stmt from @sql;
  execute stmt;
  drop prepare stmt;
end;
//

delimiter ;

call sp_so_q23692874();
-- select @sql;
```

I am not exactly sure how you are going to use this, because have a dynamic alias name on an expression name may be good if result set has only one row. You can't give a new name for an expression on each row and that makes no sense too. And that is the reason why I put a `LIMIT` clause on `grp` result set.

Comment: Post your output on some site like *http://pastebin.com/* and let me know where it was as not expected.

Comment: I NEED THE COLUMN NAMES AS Orange_CS_GRP_11 ,Orange_CS_GRP_12 ,Orange_CS_GRP_13  ETC ...

Comment: Can you post output of `select @sql`?

Comment: btw: `Orange_CS_GRP` is one of your column names or value?

Comment: yes one column is Orange_CS_GRP, rest of the columns are been made by the calicilation on this column

Comment: Do you want same column name for other column name as concatenated string like `'Orange_CS_GRP_11'`, `'Orange_CS_GRP_12'`, etc. ? If yes, then there wont be any necessity for `'@grp'` variable to define the `alias` name.

Comment: when i take off the limit 1 ... it gives out an error

Comment: `LIMIT` is required. Please look into my explanation at the bottom of my answer. And, why do you want to remove it. Why don't you post a set of expected records with their expected column names??